# Compiling python with py2exe produces errors: AttributeError: 'GenericRdata' object has no attribute 'target'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pymongo, cython, py2exe

I have a collection of Python 3 source files (one of which named `event` is cythonized) which I am trying to convert to a `main.exe` using the following setup script in `setup.py`:

```
setup(
    name="event",
    cmdclass={"build_ext": build_ext},
    ext_modules=ext_modules,
    windows=[{'script': 'main.py'}],
)
```

The errors I am getting in trying to open the `main.exe` are:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 6, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 664, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 627, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
  File "mongo.pyc", line 9, in <module>
  File "pymongo\mongo_client.pyc", line 639, in __init__
  File "pymongo\uri_parser.pyc", line 500, in parse_uri
  File "pymongo\srv_resolver.pyc", line 102, in get_hosts
  File "pymongo\srv_resolver.pyc", line 86, in _get_srv_response_and_hosts
  File "pymongo\srv_resolver.pyc", line 87, in <listcomp>
AttributeError: 'GenericRdata' object has no attribute 'target'
```

I've considered converting all my .py files to .c and then compilining using MSVC into an exe, but not sure that is the right fix here.

Has anyone come across this?

Thank you very much for any responses in advance!

Comment: "I've considered converting all my .py files to .c and then compilining using MSVC into an exe, but not sure that is the right fix here." No - it really is not.

Comment: sure - but how do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Bit late after the OP's question, but just in case this is still needed, and to save anyone else the hassle in the future:

I can't confirm from OP's post exactly what your packaging process is, but I have just had the same `AttributeError: 'GenericRdata' object has no attribute 'target'` issue when packaging a project using `cx_freeze` which contains `pymongo`.
After much digging, is seems that the issue is with it not picking up the `pymongo`'s `dnspython` dependency, and I fixed it by specifying `dns` in the build options:

```
build_exe_options = {
    "packages": ["dns"],
    "excludes": ["tkinter"],
}

base = "Console"

setup(
    name="demo",
    version="0.0.0",
    description="demo exe",
    options={"build_exe": build_exe_options},
    executables=[
        Executable(
            "demo.py",
            base=base,
        )
    ]
)
```

I have not tested this with other packagers (py2exe, PyInstaller, etc), but if they have the same issue this may be the same root cause.

Comment: Thank you!! will test it out - sounds like this has been the issue

Comment: tried on py2exe, still getting the error