# pyinstaller + pymongo no worked

Tags: python, pymongo, pyinstaller

**Hello, after pyinstaller my programm no worked**

````
  File "main.py", line 16, in <module>
  File "pymongo\mongo_client.py", line 677, in __init__
  File "pymongo\uri_parser.py", line 532, in parse_uri
  File "pymongo\srv_resolver.py", line 119, in get_hosts
  File "pymongo\srv_resolver.py", line 102, in _get_srv_response_and_hosts
  File "pymongo\srv_resolver.py", line 103, in <listcomp>
AttributeError: 'GenericRdata' object has no attribute 'target'
[19304] Failed to execute script 'main' due to unhandled exception!```
````

Comment: Can you show your code to understand the peoblem?

Comment: Here exists a similar issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70097128/8961170 `seems that the issue is with it not picking up the pymongo's dnspython dependency, and I fixed it by specifying dns in the build options`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I fix problem i use old version connection** `client = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://<login>:<mypassword> @cluster0-shard-00-00.492oe.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-01.492oe.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-02.492oe.mongodb.net:27017/<dbname>?ssl=true&replicaSet=atlas-qo0xpf-shard-0&authSource=admin&retryWrites=true&w=majority")`

- **add in flag --hidden-import dns |**
  **example : "pyinstaller -F --hidden-import dns main.py"**